# Unresolved iOS build errors after Xcode 11.2, Catalina and Flutter v1.9.1+hotfix.6

Tags: ios, flutter

After upgrading, my old Flutter project using Vcode cannot build anymore with tons of errors as below. I have tried:

1. deleting Podfile.lock
2. pod cache clean --all
3. rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
4. rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
5. rm -rf Pods
6. pod deintegrate
7. pod setup
8. pod install

flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.1 19B88, locale en-SG)
• Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/peterlum/dev/flutter
• Framework revision 68587a0916 (7 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
• Engine revision b863200c37
• Dart version 2.5.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Applications/AndroidDev/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Applications/AndroidDev/sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Applications/AndroidDev/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio 3.3.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.2, Build version 11B52
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio 3.3.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 34.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] Android Studio (version 2.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin version 12.1 - the recommended minimum version is 16.0.0
    • Dart plugin version 162.2924
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.6.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • LG D855       • LGD855a710c089                       • android-arm • Android 5.0 (API 21)
    • iPhone 6 Plus • 615DAB60-6ACB-4E37-9FAD-8CF869415B60 • ios         • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4 (simulator)

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: project
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 0.9.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: "0.14.0+5" 
  google_sign_in: "4.0.7" 

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: "0.1.2"
  intl: "^0.15.8" # 0.15.7

  # Peter add
  firebase_core: "0.4.0+9" 
  cloud_firestore: "0.12.9+5" 
  firebase_storage: "3.0.6" 
  firebase_admob: "0.9.0+7"
  firebase_analytics: "5.0.2" 
  image_picker: "0.6.0+8"
  path_provider: "0.4.1"
  date_format: "1.0.5"
  numberpicker: "0.1.7"
  qr_mobile_vision: "0.2.2"
  firebase_ml_vision: "0.8.0" 
  qr_flutter: "2.0.0+51" 
  flutter_native_image:
    git: "https://github.com/btastic/flutter_native_image.git"

  connectivity: "0.4.2"
  firebase_messaging: "5.1.6" 
  package_info: "0.3.2+1" 
  share: "0.5.3"
  url_launcher: "4.1.0+1" 
  flutter_walkthrough: ^0.0.1
  country_pickers: "1.0.1"
  shared_preferences: "0.4.3"
  flutter_facebook_login: "2.0.1"
  charts_flutter: "0.5.0"
  device_info: "0.3.0" 
  http: "^0.11.3+16"

  permission_handler: "3.0.0" 
  flutter_local_notifications: "0.6.0" 
  contacts_service: "^0.0.9"
  flutter_dialogflow: "0.1.2"
  #flutter_lottie: "0.2.0"

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Example errors:
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    ios/Pods/Bolts/Bolts/iOS/BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.m:133:17: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    _view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(_view.bounds), 0.0);
                    ^
                    self->
    /Volumes/ios/Pods/Bolts/Bolts/iOS/BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.m:133:67: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    _view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(_view.bounds), 0.0);

8 warnings generated.
    /Users/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/contacts_service-0.0.9/ios/Classes/ContactsServicePlugin.m:6:4: warning: 'SwiftContactsServicePlugin' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
      [SwiftContactsServicePlugin registerWithRegistrar:registrar];

duplicate symbol '_GMVDetectorTypeProduct' in:
        /Volumes/ios/Pods/FirebaseMLVision/Frameworks/FirebaseMLVision.framework/FirebaseMLVision(GMVDetector_c7138b42e3a094afed235ab051b2ff6c.o)
        /Volumes/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(GMVDetector_d8eaeedb32b9d25ce52bdf3b39f2008d.o)

ld: 106 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Been on this for 1 week without resolution. Help appreciate very much!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  I'm also getting random errors, only because I added a new dependency in pubspec.yaml.  Very strange and frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call `flutter clean` in the root folder of your app.

Answer (score 0):

**Your project is corrupted**. I solved it by creating new Flutter project, then copy the source code there, `.yaml` file, `lib` folder and `assets`, and then rebuilding the project.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried update pod on your ios folder?

```
pod update
```

then run again your project.